# why useEffect is called twice when using useCallbackRef from use-callback-ref

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

> `useCallbackRef` is a hook provided by [`use-callback-ref`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-callback-ref) package

Why does `useEffect` triggered twice when having in the dependency array the `.current` of the `useCallbackRef` result?

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useCallbackRef } from "use-callback-ref";

function App() {
  const [useCbRefCounter, setUseCbRefCounter] = useState(0);
  const [useCbRefEffectCounter, setUseCbRefEffectCounter] = useState(0);


  const divCbRef = useCallbackRef(null, () =>
    // This is called once
    setUseCbRefCounter((counter) => counter + 1)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!divCbRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    // This is called twice
    setUseCbRefEffectCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
  }, [divCbRef.current]);
  
  // ...
}
```

(The `useEffect` is not triggered with `null` as one might think)

[Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-effect-vs-use-callback-so-8obnd) with a comparison of the number of calls when the ref is changing

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to the implementation of `useCallbackRef`.
`divCbRef.current` is a mutable object and therefore inside `useEffect` it is the same for both calls.

But the call to `useEffect` happens twice due to the fact that the first time the `divCbRef.current` is `null`, and the second time it is `HTMLDivElement`.

If you slightly change the code of the `useEffect`, then you will see why the effect is called:

```
  const currentREF = divCbRef.current;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!divCbRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(currentREF);

    // This is called twice
    setUseCbRefEffectCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
  }, [currentREF]);
```

Console output will be

```
null
<div> </div>
```